# In Vim is there a way to delete without putting text in the register?

Tags: vim, replace, vim-registers

Using Vim I often want to replace a block of code with a block that I just yanked.

But when I delete the block of code that is to be replaced, that block itself goes into the register which erases the block I just yanked. So I've got in the habit of yanking, then inserting, then deleting what I didn't want, but with large blocks of code this gets messy trying to keep the inserted block and the block to delete separate.

So what is the slickest and quickest way to replace text in Vim?

- is there a way to delete text without putting it into the register?
- is there a way to say e.g. "replace next word" or "replace up to next paragraph"
- or is the best way to somehow use the multi-register feature?

Comment: vim-easyclip (http://www.github.com/svermeulen/vim-easyclip) is designed to address this exact problem

Comment: I asked [a question, unknowingly (at the time) duplicate of your actual problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037482/replace-word-with-whats-ready-to-put-in-vi-vim), but not so much of the title question. TL;DR - replace with what you yanked using `viwp` (for `w`ord).

Comment: Best solution to first copy and then paste without worrying about buffers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13936654/12555857

Answer (score 489, accepted):

To delete something without saving it in a register, you can use the "black hole register":

```
"_d
```

Of course you could also use any of the other registers that don't hold anything you are interested in.

Comment: At first I thought this command was not working properly.  Then I realized I was using a "dead keys" version of the american keyboard.  With this keyboard layout I have to type `"<space>_d`.  The space is needed to actually type the ".

Comment: Any ideas on doing this selectively on only empty lines? (If I `dd` on an empty line it goes into the blackhole, otherwise it `dd`s like normal).

Comment: I had trouble with this for a while, then it started working.  I'm can't imagine what I was doing wrong.

Comment: To remove one character, try: ```"_x```

Comment: This is one area where a standard text editor wins. You simply press the delete key.

Comment: It would be much more useful to map «Yank/Cut/Paste» to one register, and a deletion to another — such a way I still can got what I deleted, and don't mess with my yank. I did such a thing in Emacs, are there a way to do this in VIM?

Comment: You can also yank something with `yy` or '3yy' (or whatever), which puts it in the unnamed register, but also in 0. You can then keep pasting it with `"0p`, despite having used `d` after that.

Comment: @Hi-Angel My answer a bit below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32488853/398844) explains how to set up such a configuration with minimal changes to the default behaviour.

Comment: @VincePanuccio No. You can just press x in vim to delete a key, just like in a standard text editor,  but the question here is how to to delete the key without moving the deleted character into the buffer, so that you can still paste what was in the buffer before you did the delete.  Good luck doing that in notepad.

Comment: @VincePanuccio @Alex I just put in my .vimrc the lines `noremap x "_x` and `noremap X "_X`,
which give (respectively) forward delete and backspace functionality in normal mode. Prevents saving single characters in the register.

Comment: Welcome to vim, where complex text manipulations are easy, and ironically paste is `"+gp` and _delete_ is `"_d`

Comment: This register is also useful when deleting gigantic sections of text to, for example, selectively restore tables out of a database dump. Using `d` by itself can cause vi to exhaust the system's memory and the OOM killer will fix that by killing vi. `"_d` bypasses storing the huge section of text in RAM.

Comment: Tried this in visual block mode but it goes to start of line without deleting anything for me (suggestions welcome, ideally if possible without remapping in the .vimrc)

Comment: how to do this in command mode.  Like If I want to delete line 1 to 5, I can do this `:1,5d`. How to do this without copying the lines

Answer (score 111):

Yep. It's slightly more convoluted than deleting the "old" text first, but:

I start off with..

```
line1
line2
line3
line4

old1
old2
old3
old4
```

I <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> select the line1, line 2, 3 and 4, and delete them with the <kbd>d</kbd> command

Then I delete the old 1-4 lines the same way.

Then, do

```
"2p
```

That'll paste the second-last yanked lines (line 1-4). `"3p` will do the third-from-last, and so on..

So I end up with

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

**Reference:**
[Vim documentation on numbered register](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#quote_number)

Comment: If you select lines with <Shift-v> you delete them with just d, not dd

Comment: 1 to 9 works for deletions. To paste last thing really yanked (with 'y') you have to use "0p. That's useful in cases where you first yanks something intending to replace something else, but then the something else overwrites the default paste register.

Comment: For more undo sophistication check out [the *Gundo* (graphical undo) script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3304).

Comment: @RafaeldeF.Ferreira: Your comment isn't an answer to this question, but it actually solves probably the actual problem that led the OP to ask the question in the first place. For me, that was the real problem.

Answer (score 86):

VIM docs: *Numbered register 0 contains the text from the most recent yank command,
unless the command specified another register with ["x].*

E.g. we yank "foo" and delete "bar" - the register 0 still contains "foo"! Hence "foo" can be pasted using `"0p`

Therefore, pasting from register `0` could be one answer to the question "what is the best way to somehow use the multi-register feature?".

E.g. map `<Leader>0` as a shortcut to paste from register 0.

```
nnoremap <Leader>0 "+p
```

This way, the normal `p` or `P` can be used to paste from the unnamed register (the default behavior) and when you specifically want to paste from the last yank, use `<Leader>0`.

Answer (score 58):

It's handy to have an easy mapping which lets you replace the current selection with buffer.

For example when you put this in your .vimrc

```
" it's a capital 'p' at the end
vmap r "_dP
```

then, after copying something into register (i.e. with 'y'), you can just select the text which you want to be replaced, and simply hit 'r' on your keyboard. The selection will be substituted with your current register.

Explanation:

```
vmap - mapping for visual mode
"_d - delete current selection into "black hole register"
P - paste
```

Comment: For a more advanced version, check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290465/vim-how-to-paste-over-without-overwriting-register/290723#290723

Comment: I'd like to use `vmap <C-P> "_dP`

Comment: You can just put the text without deleting the selection. For example `Vp` replaces your current line with the yanked one right away.

Comment: This solution doesn't fix issue with `d` that is being often used for deletion.

Answer (score 44):

I put the following in my vimrc:

```
noremap  y "*y
noremap  Y "*Y
noremap  p "*p
noremap  P "*P
vnoremap y "*y
vnoremap Y "*Y
vnoremap p "*p
vnoremap P "*P
```

Now I yank to and put from the clipboard register, and don't have to care what happens with the default register. An added benefit is that I can paste from other apps with minimal hassle. I'm losing some functionality, I know (I am no longer able to manage different copied information for the clipboard register and the default register), but I just can't keep track of more than one register/clipboard anyway.

Comment: Instead of all those remaps, you could also `set clipboard=unnamed` or `set clipboard=unnamedplus`, which changes the default clipboard to `*` or `+`, respectively.

Comment: @Steve If you do that, then d will overwrite the last yank to the clipboard register also, which is what the question is trying to avoid.

Comment: @79E09796, I didn't mean to imply that it would; I was commenting on this answer and not the original question.

Comment: I put these in my .vimrc and now yanking does not work. Any idea why?

Comment: @tba replace noremap with nnoremap (two n's) and it should work fine.

Comment: This didn't work for me. But this `xnoremap p "_dP` does from 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28726374/588759

Comment: what functionality does this block? I am not a particularly advanced vim copy/paste user, so I expect I wont' run into it

Comment: @francojposa I updated the answer to clarify, I was simply referring to the fact that I am no longer able to manage different copied information for the clipboard register and the default register, which is fine because I just can't keep track of more than one register/clipboard anyway.

Answer (score 31):

All yank and delete operations write to the unnamed register by default. However, the most recent yank and most recent delete are always stored (separately) in the numbered registers. The register `0` holds the most recent yank. The registers `1-9` hold the 9 most recent deletes (with `1` being the most recent).

In other words, **a delete overwrites the most recent yank in the unnamed register, but it's still there in the `0` register.** The blackhole-register trick (`"_dd`) mentioned in the other answers works because it prevents overwriting the unnamed register, but it's not necessary.

You reference a register using double quotes, so pasting the most recently yanked text can be done like this:

```
"0p
```

This is an excellent reference:

- http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/advanced-vim-registers/

Answer (score 24):

For the specific example that you gave, if I understand the question then this might work:

```
*Highlight what you want to put somewhere else
*delete (d)
*Highlight the code that you want it to replace
*paste (p)
```

Comment: This works well except when you want to paste over multiple selections.

Answer (score 16):

To emphasize what [EBGreen said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-delete-without-putting-text-in-the-register/54272#54272):

If you paste while selecting text, the selected text is **replaced** with the pasted text.

If you want to copy some text and then paste it in multiple locations, use `"0p` to paste. Numbered register 0 contains the text from the most recent yank command.

---

Also, you can list the contents of all of your registers:

```
:registers
```

That command makes it easier to figure out what register you want when doing something like [dbr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-delete-without-putting-text-in-the-register/58637#58637). You'll also see the /,%,# registers. (See also `:help registers`)

---

And finally, check out `cW` and `cW` to change a word including and not including an trailing space. (Using capital `W` includes punctuation.)

Answer (score 14):

**A minimal invasive solution for the lazy ones:**

Register `0` always contains the last yank (as [Rafael](/questions/54255/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-delete-without-putting-text-in-the-register#comment-6335532), [alex2k8](/questions/54255/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-delete-without-putting-text-in-the-register#answer-509557) and [idbrii](/questions/54255/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-delete-without-putting-text-in-the-register#answer-2557670) have already mentioned). Unfortunately selecting register `0` all the time can be quite annoying, so it would be nice if `p` uses `"0` by default. This can be achieved by putting the following lines into your `.vimrc`:

```
noremap p "0p
noremap P "0P
for s:i in ['"','*','+','-','.',':','%','/','=','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    execute 'noremap "'.s:i.'p "'.s:i.'p'
    execute 'noremap "'.s:i.'P "'.s:i.'P'
endfor
```

The first line maps each `p` stroke to `"0p`. However, this prevents `p` from accessing any other registers. Therefore all `p` strokes with an explicitly selected register are mapped to the equivalent commandline expression within the for-loop. The same is done for `P`.

This way the standard behaviour is preserved, except for the implicit `p` and `P` strokes, which now use register `0` by default.

**Hint 1:** The cut command is now `"0d` instead of just `d`. But since I'm lazy  this is way too long for me ;) Therefore I'm using the following mapping:

```
noremap <LEADER>d "0d
noremap <LEADER>D "0D
```

The leader key is `\` by default, so you can easily cut text by typing `\d` or `\D`.

**Hint 2:** The default timeout for multi-key mappings is pretty short. You might want to increase it to have more time when selecting a register. See `:help timeoutlen` for details, I'm using:

```
set timeout timeoutlen=3000 ttimeoutlen=100
```

Answer (score 10):

If you're using Vim then you'll have the visual mode, which is like selecting, but with the separating modes thing that's the basis of vi/vim.

What you want to do is use visual mode to select the source, then yank, then use visual mode again to select the scope of the destination, and then paste to text from the default buffer.

Example:

In a text file with:

```
1| qwer
2| asdf
3| zxcv
4| poiu
```

with the following sequence: `ggVjyGVkp` you'll end with:

```
1| qwer
2| asdf
3| qewr
4| asdf
```

Explained:

- `gg`: go to first line
- `V`: start visual mode with whole lines
- `j`: go down one line (with the selection started on the previous lines this grows the selection one line down)
- `y`: yank to the default buffer (the two selected lines, and it automatically exits you from visual mode)
- `G`: go to the last line
- `V`: start visual mode (same as before)
- `k`: go up one line (as before, with the visual mode enabled, this grows the selection one line up)
- `p`: paste (with the selection on the two last lines, it will replace those lines with whatever there is in the buffer -- the 2 first lines in this case)

This has the little inconvenient that puts the last block on the buffer, so it's somehow not desired for repeated pastings of the same thing, so you'll want to save the source to a named buffer with something like `"ay` (to a buffer called "a") and paste with something like `"ap` (but then if you're programming, you probably don't want to paste several times but to create a function and call it, right? **RIGHT**?).

If you are only using vi, then youll have to use invisible marks instead the visual mode, `:he mark` for more on this, I'm sorry but I'm not very good with this invisible marks thing, I'm pretty contaminated with visual mode.

Answer (score 10):

For 'replace word', try `cw` in normal mode.

For 'replace paragraph', try `cap` in normal mode.

Comment: For 'replace *up to* next paragraph', try `c}` in normal mode.

Comment: Why "cap" does this? Isn't "a" and "p" stand for "append" and "paste"?

Comment: @WiSaGaN "ap" stands for "a paragraph" : https://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#object-select

Answer (score 7):

Well, first do this command:

```
:h d
```

Then you will realize that you can delete into a specific register. That way you won't alter what is in your default register.

Comment: `["x]d{motion}    Delete text that {motion} moves over [into register x]` -- Vim `:h d`

Answer (score 6):

My situation: in `Normal` mode, when I delete characters using the `x` keypress, those deletions overwrite my latest register -- complicating edits where I want to delete characters using `x` and paste something I have in my most recent register (e.g. pasting the same text at two or more places).

I tried the suggestion in the accepted answer (`"_d`), but it did not work.

However, from the accepted answer/comments at https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/122/performing-certain-operations-without-clearing-register, I added this to my `~/.vimrc`, which works (you may have to restart Vim):

```
nnoremap x "_x
```

That is, I can now do my normal yank (`y`), delete (`d`), and paste (`p`) commands -- and characters I delete using `x` no longer populate the most recent registers.

Answer (score 6):

Vim's occasional preference for complexity over practicality burdens the user with applying registers to copy/delete actions -- when more often than not, one just wants paste what was copied and "forget" what was deleted.

However, instead of fighting vim's complicated registers, make them more convenient: choose a "default" register to store your latest delete. For example, send deletes to the d register (leaving a-c open for ad-hoc usage; d is a nice mnemonic):

```
nnoremap d "dd           "send latest delete to d register
nnoremap D "dD           "send latest delete to d register 
nnoremap dd "ddd         "send latest delete to d register
nnoremap x "_x           "send char deletes to black hole, not worth saving
nnoremap <leader>p "dp   "paste what was deleted
nnoremap <leader>P "dP   "paste what was deleted
```

This approach prevents deletes from clobbering yanks BUT doesn't forfeit  registering the delete -- one can paste (back) what was deleted instead of losing it in a black hole (as in the accepted answer).  In the example above, this recalling is done with two leader p mappings. A benefit of this approach, is that it gives you the ability to choose what to paste: (a) what was just yanked, or (b) what was just deleted.

Comment: Great solution. Slightly more intuitive paste mappings for me  are `nnoremap dp "dp` and `nnoremap dP "dP`.

Comment: This is great. Love it.

Answer (score 5):

I found a very useful mapping for your purpose:

```
xnoremap p "_dP
```

Deleted text is put in "black hole register", and the yanked text remains.

Source: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Replace_a_word_with_yanked_text

Answer (score 4):

Text deleted, while in insert mode, doesn't go into default register.

Comment: but deleting any significant amount of text in default mode is SLOW

Answer (score 4):

The two solutions I use in the right contexts are;

- highlight what you want to replace using Vims `VISUAL` mode then paste the register.

I use this mostly out of habit as I only found the second solution much later, eg

```
yiw   " yank the whole word
viwp  " replace any word with the default register
```

- [YankRing](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1234). With this plugin you can use the keybinding `<ctrl>+<p>` to replace the previous numbered register with the one you just pasted.

Basically you go about pasting as you would, but when you realise that you have since overwritten the default register thus losing what you actually wanted to paste you can `<C-P>` to find and replace from the YankRing history!

One of those must have plugins...

Answer (score 2):

In the windows version (probably in Linux also), you can yank into the system's copy/paste buffer using `"*y` (i.e. preceding your yank command with double-quotes and asterisk).

You can then delete the replaceable lines normally and paste the copied text using `"*p`.

Answer (score 2):

I often make a mistake when following the commands to 'y'ank then '"_d'elete into a black hole then 'p'aste. I prefer to 'y'ank, then delete however I like, then '"0p' from the 0 register, which is where the last copied text gets pushed to.

Answer (score 2):

For Dvorak users, one very convenient method is to just delete unneeded text into the "1 register instead of the "_ black hole register, if only because you can press " + 1 with the same shift press and a swift pinky motion since 1 is the key immediately above " in Dvorak (PLUS d is in the other hand, which makes the whole command fast as hell).

Then of course, the "1 register could be used for other things because of it's convenience, but unless you have a purpose more common than replacing text I'd say it's a pretty good use of the register.

Answer (score 2):

For emacs-evil users, the function `(evil-paste-pop)` can be triggered after pasting, and cycles through previous entries in the kill-ring. Assuming you bound it to `<C-p>` (default in Spacemacs), you would hit `p` followed by as many `<C-p>` as needed.

Answer (score 2):

For those who use JetBrans IDE (PhpStorm, WebStorm, IntelliJ IDEA) with IdeaVim. You may be experiencing problems with remapping like `nnoremap d "_d` and using it to delete a line `dd`. Possible solution for you: `nnoremap dd "_dd`

There are issues on youtrack, please vote for them: 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-1189
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-1363

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to post this reply. I have looked everywhere in the world to fix this issue with IdeaVim.

Answer (score 2):

The following vscode setting should allow e.g. dd and dw to become "_dd and "_dw, which work correctly now with our remapper.

```
{
     "vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
        {
            "before": ["d"],
            "after": [ "\"", "_", "d" ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who are primary interested of not overwriting the unnamed register when you replace a text via virtual selection and paste.

You could use the following solution which is easy and works best for me:

`xnoremap <expr> p 'pgv"'.v:register.'y'`

It's from the answers (and comments) here:
[How to paste over without overwriting register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290465/how-to-paste-over-without-overwriting-register)

It past the selection first, then the selection with the new text is selected again (gv). Now the register which was last used in visual mode (normally the unnamed register but works also side effect free if you use another register for pasting). And then yank the new value to the register again.

PS: If you need a simpler variant which works also with intellj idea plugin vim-simulation you can take this one (downside: overwrite unnamed register even if another register was given for pasting):

`vnoremap p pgvy`

Answer (score 1):

register 0 thru 9 are the latest things you yank or cut etc, and DO NOT include deleted things etc. So if you yank/cut something, it is in register 0 also, even if you say deleted stuff all day after that, register 0 is still the last stuff you yanked/cut.

yiw #goes to both default register, and register 0

## it yanks the word the cursor is in

## deleted stuff etc will go to default register, but NOT register 0

## in standard mode:

"0p #put the content of register 0

## in insert mode:

ctrl-r 0 #put the content of register 0

I also had a friend who always yanked/cut to register x lol.

Comment: I already knew about `viw`, but never realized about : `ciw` `diw` `yiw`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm just newbee, but I completly don't understand logic behind implementation of working with registers in (N)Vim. I have spent a lot of time trying to keep my unnamed+ register clear of garbage deletions in nvim. Remapping and plugins like cutlass.nvim doesn't fit to me because they conflicts with the which-key plugin, so I wrote an autocommand:

```
vim.cmd([[
  augroup SyncUnnamedRegister
    autocmd!
      autocmd TextYankPost * if !v:event.visual || v:event.operator == 'c' | let @+ = @0 |  endif
  augroup END
]])
```

That keeps the unnamedplus register synced with last yank register ("0"), except for cutting in visual mode

To delete instead of cut with 'd' or 'D' I have to remap 'd', 'D' in visual mode:

```
"d" to '"1d' - Delete in register 1 (visual mode)
"D" to '"1D' - Delete line in register 1 (visual mode)"
"<leader>D" to '"_d' - "Delete in blackhole register (for huge amount of text, for example)"
```

So, now all commands in normal mode and 'd', 'D' in visual mode works as they did by default, but unnamed+ register keep last yanked text, in visual mode 'x' and 'X' are used to cut text in unnamed+ register

Updated:
To keep the unnamed+ register clear of deletions for both paste over text an deleting change:

```
autocmd TextYankPost * if !v:event.visual || v:event.operator == 'c' | let @+ = @0 |  endif
```

with:

```
  autocmd TextYankPost * if v:event.operator == 'c' || v:event.operator == 'd' | let @+ = @0 |  endif
```

and add remap in visual mode (if you want to cut with `x` and `s`):

```
 "x" to 'ygvx' "Cut (visual mode)"
 "s" to 'ygvs', desc = "Cut and insert (visual mode)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple macro with:
`q"_dwq`

Now to delete the next word without overwriting the register, you can use `@d`

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is to use `p` when in visual mode. Following function will recover the content of unnamed register after you paste something in visual mode.

```
 function! MyPaste(ex)
  let save_reg = @"
  let reg = v:register
  let l:count = v:count1
  let save_map = maparg('_', 'v', 0, 1)
  exec 'vnoremap _ '.a:ex
  exec 'normal gv"'.reg.l:count.'_'
  call mapset('v', 0, save_map)
  let @" = save_reg
endfunction

vmap p :<c-u>call MyPaste('p')<cr>
vmap P :<c-u>call MyPaste('P')<cr>
```

Usage is the same as before and the content of register " is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to yank into the 'p' buffer to begin with.

#### Copy (aka: yank)

```
# highlight text you want to copy, then:
"py
```

#### Paste

```
# delete or highlight the text you want to replace, then:
"pp
```

Pros (As opposed to deleting into a specific register):

- `"pp` is easy on the fingers
- Not going to accidentally overwrite your paste buffer on delete.

Answer (score 0):

`noremap mm m`

and

`noremap mx "_x`

is how I deal with it.