# How to paste over without overwriting register

Tags: vim, vi

Does anyone know of a way to paste over a visually selected area without having the selection placed in the default register?

I know I can solve the problem by always pasting from an explicit register. But it's a pain in the neck to type <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> instead of just <kbd>p</kbd>

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`"{register}p` won't work as you describe. It will replace the selection with the content of the register. You will have instead to do something like:

```
" I haven't found how to hide this function (yet)
function! RestoreRegister()
  let @" = s:restore_reg
  return ''
endfunction

function! s:Repl()
    let s:restore_reg = @"
    return "p@=RestoreRegister()\<cr>"
endfunction

" NB: this supports "rp that replaces the selection by the contents of @r
vnoremap <silent> <expr> p <sid>Repl()
```

Which should be fine as long as you don't use a plugin that has a non-nore vmap to p, and that expects a register to be overwritten.

This code is available as a script [there](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/plugin/repl-visual-no-reg-overwrite.vim). Ingo Karkat also defined a [plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2703) solving the same issue.

Comment: Actually, I though there was a neat way to fetch the register used, but couldn't remember how. Hence the complexity of the function.

Comment: I think that this is overkill, won't remember the `regtype` (linewise?) and that remapping p to `pgvy` is sufficient.

Comment: It may be overkill, but it has no side effect. On a `"xp`, this does not overwrite `@"` contents with `@x` unlike `pgvy`

Comment: then what about `:xnoremap p pgv@=v:register.'y'<cr>` ?

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I've also tried downloading the script. Here's the list of commands I do: First I press v, then e to to select to the end of the word, then y to yank it. After that, I go to a different word that I want to replace. I press v, e then p to replace that one. Then I do it again, but this time the next word is replaced by the one I replaced earlier.

Comment: Eddy, what does `:verbose vmap p` and `:verbose vmap x`  tell you ? BTW, have you checked this patch http://stackoverflow.com/a/4446608/15934 ?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it by applying danprice's patch to the repl-visual-no-reg-overwrite.vim plugin

Answer (score 54):

Use the following:

```
xnoremap p pgvy
```

this will reselect and re-yank any text that is pasted in visual mode.

Edit: in order this to work with `"xp` you can do:

```
xnoremap p pgv"@=v:register.'y'<cr>
```

`v:register` expands to the last register name used in a normal mode command.

Comment: On a `"xp`, this approach overwrites `@"` with `@x`.

Comment: Your suggestion of `xnoremap p pgv"@=v:register.'y'<cr>` didn't work for me. This, however, does: `xnoremap <expr> p 'pgv"'.v:register.'y'`

Comment: This looks interesting. Could you add a line about what `g` does? I've not seen it before.

Comment: @LondonRob: `g` alone does nothing. It provides extended, multi-key commands, like `z`. For example, `go` goes to nth byte in buffer, `gj` and `gk` go to next and previous displayed line (differ from `jk` when lines are wrapped), `ga` displays information on character under the cursor, `gJ` joins lines without space, and here `gv` restores last visual selection. You can use `:help gv`.

Comment: @mark  ``:xnoremap <expr> p 'pgv"'.v:register.'y`>' ``, I added `` `>`` To restore the cursor position

Comment: Thanks @LondonRob for the great explanation of what the hell the `gv` in `pgvy` does. I've seen this solution before and used it but hadn't quite realized what it was doing.

Comment: Almost do it, but using Ctrl+V (for column selection) only works first time. On a second Ctrl+V it only replaces on first line and remove other lines selection

Comment: Without remap all that needs to be remembered is pressing `gvy` after pasting.

Answer (score 47):

I don't like the default vim behavior of copying all text deleted with `d`, `D`, `c`, or `C` into the default register.

I've gotten around it by mapping `d` to `"_d`, `c` to `"_c`, and so on.

From my .vimrc:

```
"These are to cancel the default behavior of d, D, c, C
"  to put the text they delete in the default register.
"  Note that this means e.g. "ad won't copy the text into
"  register a anymore.  You have to explicitly yank it.
nnoremap d "_d
vnoremap d "_d
nnoremap D "_D
vnoremap D "_D
nnoremap c "_c
vnoremap c "_c
nnoremap C "_C
vnoremap C "_C
```

Comment: As useful as these mappings are (I do something similar myself), they do not answer OP's question, p will still overwrite what you yanked pasting over selected content.

Answer (score 40):

Use `P` to paste without yanking the deleted text.

[:help v_P](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#v_P)

> With P the unnamed register is not changed (and neither the selection or clipboard), you can repeat the same change.

This behavior was introduced in [v8.2.4242](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.4242) (2022-01-28) and refined in [v8.2.4881](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.4881) (2022-05-06).

Or if your muscle memory is too strong:

```
xnoremap p P
```

Comment: I just tested it a little and it appears to work. This is the type of much-less-intrusive solution I was looking for. I have to remote into too many machines to have to carry around a bunch of keymaps.

Comment: dude, love you. i hated it so much in vim. thank you!

Answer (score 26):

In your `.vimrc`

```
xnoremap p "_dP
```

I found this from a response on a similar thread, but the original source was http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Replace_a_word_with_yanked_text.  It mentions some drawbacks, however it works fine for me.

Comment: This seems like the simplest solution.

Comment: Worked for me. And this answer is clear. `.vimrc.local` is OK too.

Comment: Doesn't work if your selection extends to the end of the line.

Comment: This causes some visual flicking for me (vim redraws inbetween the commands).
`xnoremap <silent> p p:let @+=@0<CR>:let @"=@0<CR>` does not have that issue

Comment: Almost seven years of using vim and only now I learn that `P` puts the text before the cursor compared to `p`, which does after the text.

Answer (score 6):

Luc Hermitte's solution works like a charm. I was using it for about a week or so. Then I discovered a solution from [Steve Losh's .vimrc](https://github.com/sjl/dotfiles/blob/eea18b00b8c74943f5094fddf91d3c2a7e0a7242/vim/vimrc#L1294) that works nicely if YankRing is part of your plugin/bundle lineup:

```
function! YRRunAfterMaps()                                                                                                      
    " From Steve Losh, Preserve the yank post selection/put.    
    vnoremap p :<c-u>YRPaste 'p', 'v'<cr>gv:YRYankRange 'v'<cr> 
endfunction
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
xnoremap <expr> p 'pgv"'.v:register.'y'
```

- `xnoremap` means that this is only for `Visual` mode, not `Visual + Select` modes.
- `<expr>` means that `{rhs}` of the `xnoremap {lhs} {rhs}` setting is evaluated as an expression.
- In this case, our expression of `'pgv"'.v:register.'y'` is using `.` for  concatenation.
- `v:register` is evaluated to the register being used during the fulfillment of the mapping.

The result of `"xp` would evaluate to `pgv"xy`, where `x` is the register.

I was helped by an answer to this stackoverflow question: [Vim - mapping with an optional register prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954866/vim-mapping-with-an-optional-register-prefix#answer-9957686)
in conjunction with [Benoit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/457352)'s answer [on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290465/vim-how-to-paste-over-without-overwriting-register/290723#answer-5093286)

Answer (score 5):

Luc's function worked well for me after I made a change to support the fact that I have clipboard=unnamed set:

```
function! RestoreRegister()
    let @" = s:restore_reg
    if &clipboard == "unnamed"
        let @* = s:restore_reg
    endif
    return ''
endfunction
```

Comment: For reference: using `clipboard=unnamedplus` this has to be `@+` instead of `@*`.

Answer (score 2):

Luc Hermitte's did the trick! Really good. Here's his solution put in a toggle function, so you can switch between normal behavior and no-replace-register put.

the command ,u toggles the behavior

```
let s:putSwap = 1 
function TogglePutSwap()
    if s:putSwap
        vnoremap <silent> <expr> p <sid>Repl()
        let s:putSwap = 0 
        echo 'noreplace put'
    else
        vnoremap <silent> <expr> p p 
        let s:putSwap = 1 
        echo 'replace put'
    endif
    return
endfunction
noremap ,p :call TogglePutSwap()<cr>
```

Comment: You can also change s:Repl to return "p" instead of "p@=RestoreRegister()\<cr>" depending on s:putSwap value.

Comment: prefer `silent! vunmap` instead of `vnoremap <silent> <expr> p p`

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution.

```
vnoremap p p:let @+=@0<CR>

vnoremap P P:let @+=@0<CR>
```

I find out after paste, the old content is still stored in "0 register.
Just restore it to current clipboard by

```
:let @+=@0
```

Comment: This works well but only if `clipboard` has "unnamedplus".

Comment: If "unnamedplus" is not in `clipboard`: `xnoremap <expr> <silent>p 'p:let @' . v:register . '=@0<CR>'`

Answer (score 0):

duct-tape programming, but works for me:

```
nmap viwp viwpyiw
nmap vi'p vi'pyi'
nmap vi"p vi"pyi"
nmap vi(p vi(pyi(
nmap vi[p vi[pyi[
nmap vi<p vi<pyi<
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the text and paste by `P`(uppercase).

Example:

```
viwP
```

See [`h: v_P`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#v_P) for more infomation.

Answer (score 0):

map `"<leader>p"` to `'"_d<Left>p'` for visual mode.

this will allow you to highlight the text you want to paste over, hit `<leader>p` and paste the text from the current buffer over it - *without* copying the highlighted text to your register. Meaning the previous text stays in your `""` register.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76436862/20645126) how not to copy deletions in unnamed+ register (or, in fact, overwrite register back to last yank).
In the same way you can do when pasting with that autocommand:

```
vim.cmd([[
  augroup SyncUnnamedRegister
    autocmd!
      autocmd TextYankPost * if v:event.visual || v:event.operator == 'd' | let @+ = @0 |  endif
  augroup END
]])
```

Answer (score -4):

try -

```
:set guioptions-=a
:set guioptions-=A
```

Comment: Those control whether selected text is added to the windowing system's clipboard (e.g., X11 or Win32), not to Vim's internal copy registers.