# vim copy and replace text

Tags: vim, copy-paste

Lets say that i have this text:

```
$test = 'lorem';
$test2= 'ipsum';
```

and I want to copy lorem and paste into ipsum.
I tried to do `yi'` on lorem and then went on ipsum and did `ci'` but that replaced my pastebin with ipsum. and my previous copy was lost.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**yi'** on lorem, move to i of ipsum, **vep**?

Comment: Ok, but now the register contains ipsum.

Comment: Hm, so it does.  Experiments with . show that it implements the paste-replace using a delete, which puts ipsum in your default register.  Seems this is hard to prevent; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290465/vim-how-to-paste-over-without-overwriting-register has a hideously involved solution.

Comment: Easy to solve:

"kyi' on lorem, move to i of ipsum, ve"kp?

This yanks lorem into register k, pastes it over ipsum from register k, and keeps it in register k ready to paste again anywhere else you might want to put it. ipsum still ends up in the default register, but that's no longer a problem and could be useful too.

Comment: Oops, typo in the above. That should have been:

"kyi' on lorem, move to i of ipsum, ve"kp

Comment: I've copied my solution to a new answer; feel free to vote it up!

Answer (score 9):

Easy:

"kyi' on lorem, move to i of ipsum, ve"kp

This yanks lorem *into* register k, pastes it over ipsum *from* register k, and *keeps* it in register k ready to paste again anywhere else you might want to put it. ipsum still ends up in the default register, but that's no longer a problem and could be useful too.

If you've already got something in register k, you can use a different register instead (just use a different key).

Answer (score 7):

I usually go to the sed command.

```
:%s/ipsum/lorem/g
```

- `%` means do this for every line
- `s` means sed, or search and replace
- `g` at the end means replace every `ipsum` with `lorem`; if you omit this, it only replaces the first.

Comment: i dont want to use replace since that means i have to type it

Comment: A little bit of work if you don't want to type either word, but you can use C-R C-W to paste the word under the cursor, e.g.: :%s/<C-R><C-W>/<ESC>, move cursor to ipsum, :<UP><C-R><C-W>/g

Answer (score 3):

Go to the l of lorem, ye (yank to end of word).
Go to the i of ipsum, "_de (delete to end of word, putting the deleted text in the black hole register.
P (paste register before cursor).

Altogether: yej"_deP

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you yank into a named buffer, using `"ayi'`, then delete and paste with `d'i"aP`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what do you want exactly.

You have this on two lines:

```
$test = 'lorem';
$test2= 'ipsum';
```

If you go to l and yw, it yanks lorem,
then go to i of ipsum, and cw, and p and it will replace ipsum with lorem.
You will still have both lorem and ipsum in the registers.

You can get the contents of those registers with :reg

If you want to paste something from them then "*p, or ":p, or "0p (you'll see it when you type :reg)

Answer (score 1):

`vi'y` on *lorem*

`vi'p` on *ipsum*

`gvy` to copy back *lorem* to register for possible macro with `vi'p`

(`qa` - `gvy` - `j` - `vi'p` - `q` - `@a` - `@@` - `@@` ...)

Answer (score 0):

Words here to stop Markdown treating the code that follows as plain text.

```
/lorem
"adw
/ipsum
"aP"bdw
``
"bp
```

The first text searches for 'lorem'; the next deletes the word into the buffer named 'a', leaving a pair of empty quotes behind in the text.  The next search finds 'ipsum'; the `"aP` pulls the buffer named 'a' in before the word ipsum; the `"bdw` deletes the word into the buffer named 'b', leaving 'lorem' behind.  The double back-tick goes back to the place the last search came from - the empty quotes; and `"bp` pulls the named buffer after the first quote.

You can also omit the `"a` and `"b`, but this way, the values are in the named buffers `"a` and `"b` and can be copied again, and again, and again until you don't need the values any more.

Answer (score 0):

After you do `ci'` on impsum your lorem is in register `"0`. So, you can do `ci'^R0` (`^R` means `Ctrl+r`) and paste your lorem in place of ipsum.

See `:help quote_number` for more info on numbered registers.

Answer (score -2):

You want to use `y` to copy a selection and `p` to paste.

[Here is a good list to keep handy.](http://www.pixelbeat.org/vim.tips.html)