# Can vim replace a text object with the default register?

Tags: vim

Example: I have some text, like this php code

```
if(empty($condition)) {
    // work here...
}
```

And my default register contains the string "$NewCondition".

I want to place the cursor inside the first set of parens `(...)` and perform a command that will result in this:

```
if($NewCondition) {
    // work here...
}
```

So my question: Is there some way to replace the text inside the parens using the default register?

Most suggestions I've found, [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619194/vim-copy-and-replace-text/619233#619233), fail when there's nested parens.

I also know I can name registers, such as `"ayi(` to yank all text in parens into register `a`, but I don't want to have to type two extra characters every time I'm yanking. That's why I'm asking about the default register.

In an ideal solution the default register would still contain "$NewCondition" when the replace is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vi("_dP
```

- `vi(` to select `empty($condition)`
- `"_d` to delete it into the blackhole register
- `P` to put the content of the default register before the cursor which is now on the last `)`

I use this a lot so I have this mapping to make the whole thing shorter:

```
vnoremap <Leader>p "_dP
```

so (with `,` as the mapleader) I do `vi(,p`.

As a side note, if your cursor is in the second set of parenthesis you can do `vi(i(` to go one level up and so on.

Comment: I did not know about using `i(i(` to go up a level, very useful.

Answer (score 4):

```
vi)p
```

Unfortunately this will also place the old text in the default register.

Comment: Overwriting the default register can be fixed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290465/vim-how-to-paste-over-without-overwriting-register

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `"_ci)<c-r>"<esc>`

Some detailed explanations here: `"_` means to select the "black-hole" register for the following command.  So the text that gets deleted in your next operation will simply be discarded and will not be put into any registers.  `ci)` means "change inner parentheses", it will delete all the text within current level of parenthesis pair, then bring you into insert mode.  `<c-r>` in insert mode means to insert the text in a specified register into the current cursor position, and `"` selects the "default register".  At last, we use `<esc>` to bring us back to normal mode.

Indeed a lot of key strokes!  If you use such operation very often, you can consider creating a keymap for it.  See `:help map` for more details.