# how to replace a current line with what in a buffer using vi

Tags: vim, buffer

Say  i have line stored in buffer k. how do I replace some line with the content of the buffer?

Comment: I suppose this would do, or are you looking for something else: dd"kP

Comment: on the same, note how to copy a line into the buffer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, the overall answer is to use dd"kP.  I'd like to add that you might want to use :g, so that if you want to replace all lines that match 'foo' with the content of register k, you can do:

```
:g/foo/normal dd"kP
```

Note that using p instead of P will cause some problems if the first line of your buffer matches the pattern.

Answer (score 7):

go anywhere on the line to be replaced.  Execute a buffer P (Put above).  Use dd to delete the current line.

so "xPdd

Answer (score 5):

Go on the line you wish to change, and execute

```
V"kp
```

Comment: The only downside to this one is that in gvim it'd be likely to alter the contents of the system clipboard.

Comment: Just fix v_p then -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290465/vim-how-to-paste-over-without-overwriting-register/290723#290723

Comment: Haha, yes I suppose that's a possibility.

Answer (score 3):

best way i can think on the spot is

"ayy (this yanks / copies the line to the "a buffer

then

dd (delete the line to the standard buffer)

then

"aP which inserts buffer"a before the current line

Answer (score 1):

The quote key " is what you need.  That makes your yank/put register specific.  So you have something in register k and you wanted to replace the current line with it you'd type:

```
^c$<esc>"kp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ctrl-v and select what you want to copy and press "y" to "yank" it. Then ctrl-v or shift-v to select the "some lines" that you want to replace and press "p" to paste it.

Comment: I not copying anything on the fly. I am pre-storing certain lines that I will use to replace some line in the code.