# Vim - mapping with an optional register prefix

Tags: vim

So I've discovered that a common task for me in Vim is to PUT either to the start of the line or the end of the line.  So my mapping could be:

```
nmap <Leader>p $p
nmap <Leader>P 0P
```

However, what I'd really like to do is optionally include a register before putting.

So for example <kbd>"a,P</kbd> would put from register a to the beginning of the line.

Is there a way do this with a mapping?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using `<expr>` mapping in one line:

```
nnoremap <expr> \p '$"'.v:register.v:count1.'p'
nnoremap <expr> \P '0"'.v:register.v:count1.'P'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly possible. I first I though this solution was possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/290723/15934, but `<expr>` won't let us move the cursor as we wish, and `normal` can't be used.

Still, we can do this:

```
function! s:PutAt(where)
  " <setline($+1> appends, but <setline(0> does not insert, hence the hack
  " with getline to build a list of what should be at the start of the buffer.
  let line = a:where ==1 
        \ ? [getreg(), getline(1)]
        \ : getreg()
  call setline(a:where, line)
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <leader>P :call <sid>PutAt(1)<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>p :call <sid>PutAt(line('$')+1)<cr>
```

Comment: He was talking about adding at the beginning/end of the line, not the file. And, by the way, `<expr>` mappings do allow you to move a cursor, you should just add cursor moving commands to the result of the expression.