# How to make custom mappings as a prefix to existing/default mappings?

Tags: vim

I have a binding like this to paste above or below:

```
nmap bp o<ESC>p
nmap ap O<ESC>p
```

However its limited to paste from default register. Is it possible to make this work with any register? Like say `":bp` or `"+bp` etc ? Basically I want to prepend `o<ESC>` to my next action.

This is a duplicate of [Vim - mapping with an optional register prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954866/vim-mapping-with-an-optional-register-prefix).

Comment: Don't put comments after the mappings (as they aren't comments).

Comment: Also for this example... `P` does paste above. So no mapping needed.

Comment: p and P actually pastes above and below , but only if it has line ending right? I often small segments of text but need to dump into the next line in vim. Also sometimes paste the last used command etc.