# How can we retrieve the last word deleted

Tags: vim

Does there exist a register, option... to get the last word deleted (`dw`)?

Suppose that I have this line:

```
word_1, word_2, word_3
```

I place the cursor on w of word_2 and `dw` and I get:

```
word_1, , word_3
```

So I press `xx` to delete the `,` followed by a space.

I can't use `p` or `P` to paste word_2 because it contains a space.

I know that I could use a register to copy `word_2` into it and use `"` to paste word_2.

Thanks

=============================================

EDIT

While googling

```
delete register vim
```

I found this interesting related question:
[In vim is there a way to delete without putting text in the register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-delete-without-putting-text-in-the-register)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one register keeping the data deleted *within a line*  : `""` (well there is also `"-` but it is of little use here *since it is a copy of "" in this case*). *[text in italic added afterwards]*

It is definitely not the universal solution, but I have remapped `x` to "delete to nowhere":

```
:map x "_d
:map xx "_dd
```

This way `d` deletes to delete register and `x` does the same but doesn't litter delete register, so that I can keep valuable deleted information intact.

So in your case I would type: `dw` `2x<Right>` (or `xf<Space>`) and then `p`

Answer (score 4):

For small deletes inside one line, like deleting a word or removing single characters with `x`, no multi-level history is stored in registers.

For larger deletes (one line or more, or some special movement commends) the last nine deleted items are automatically stored in the registers 1 to 9. So if you do three deletes you can paste the text from the first one (third item in the history) with `"3p`.

For the official documentation for these registers see also `:help quote_number`.

Comment: Many thanks. I was looking for descriptions for each available register.