# How to Delete (desired text), delete (undesired text), and paste (desired text) in Vim

Tags: vim, paste

I don't know if its a retarded problem but it's a funny dilemma. When I want to delete text that I want to place somewhere else, but that place has other bunch of text that I don't want, I would delete that text, but in the process I copy a new clipboard so the previously deleted text disappear.

Any suggestions to solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**A few possible solutions:**

Delete the undesired text first :)

*or*

When deleting the desired text store it in a register other than the default register e.g. to delete the desired text to the end of the current line and store it in register *b*:

```
"bd$
```

Then delete your undesired text.

Then paste the contents of register *b*:

```
"bp
```

*or*

Delete the undesired text to the black hole register as suggested in the answer linked to by [Yarek T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/274503/yarek-t) using:

```
"_d
```

Answer (score 6):

maybe this question might shed some light onto your problem. [54255](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-delete-without-putting-text-in-the-register)

It uses the "black hole buffer" to delete lines without adding them to the yank buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use the number registers.  When you delete a chunk of text it is moved into register 1, the current contents of register 1 is moved into register 2, etc.  The contents of register 9 are discarded.  However this only works for changes longer than a line, so small deletes are not captured.

So you can delete the first region, delete the second region, then paste from register 2.

Personally I prefer to use registers a-z, but the numbered registers are useful if you delete some text and then realise you forgot to specify a register.

Do `:help "1` for more information.

You can also see what is currently in all the registers, including 1-9, with `:registers`

Answer (score 2):

Type:

```
:registers
```

And you'll get a list of registers that contain all previous deletions.  You can always pick one to paste.  E.g. for registers:

```
"1   Item1^J
"2   Item3^J
"3   Item2^J
```

pick the second one and paste it with:

```
"2p
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [yankring](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1234) plugin.