# Vim will copy the text when I delete it, but how can I disable it?

Tags: vim

I don't like automatic copy the deleted text when delete in Vim, how to disable it?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-delete-without-putting-text-in-the-register

Comment: A better approach would be to understand the strengths of having text copied into a register whenever you 'delete' a text - unless you want this feature for some obscure reason in which case you have access to the black-hole register.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Vim is there a way to delete without putting text in the register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-delete-without-putting-text-in-the-register)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure there is a way to disable it, but there is a black hole register called '_', which swallows everything, and gives nothing back.

You use it by prepending "_ to the command, so "_dd would send the current line to the blackhole.

Comment: very nice, I didn't know that!

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to disable this and have found a solution:

Add this to your .gvimrc file and autocopy text on select will be disabled.

```
  " Following three lines remove the auto copy function from VIM
  set guioptions-=a
  set guioptions-=A
  set guioptions-=aA
```