# Any way to delete in vim without overwriting your last yank?

Tags: vim, vi

I love vim, but one common gotcha is:

- yank a line
- go to where you would like to paste it
- delete what's there
- paste your yank, only to discover that it pastes what you just deleted

Obviously the workflow is delete first, yank second.  But it would be reeeeeaaaaaalllly nice if I didn't *have* to.  Anyone have a trick for this? Does vim have a paste buffer that works well, or is there a .vimrc setting I can change?

Comment: Vi purists will hate me for this, but you could also use the *mswin* behaviour. It let's you use Ctrl-C & Ctrl-V for copy & paste. It uses its own register, so you can `yy` and `dd` as much as you want. To use this behaviour add these lines to your *.vimrc*: `source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim` and `behave mswin`.

Comment: @Cristian - it uses the `*` register.  You can use vim commands to yank arbitrary movements to the system clipboard, e.g. `"*y/foo<enter>` will yank up to the next "foo" to the Windows clipboard.  (Using mswin/Ctrl-C you'd need to go into visual mode first.)

Comment: @dash-tom-bang: yeah, I wasn't remembering what register it was.

Comment: I find http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Replace_a_word_with_yanked_text highly useful and insightful.

Comment: vim-easyclip (https://github.com/svermeulen/vim-easyclip) is designed to address this exact problem

Comment: @CristianCiupitu nice idea, but msvin doesn't work (anymore?). ctrl+v is always empty.

Answer (score 375, accepted):

Pass to the `_` register, the black hole.

To delete a line without sticking it in the registers:

```
"_dd
```

See also [`:help registers`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#registers).

It's probably safest, if you want to paste something over and over again, to yank it into a "named" register.

```
"aY
```

Yanks a line into the `a` register.  Paste it with `"ap`.

Comment: Hah, didn't know about the black hole register. Thanks for the enlightenment.

Comment: The black hole register is way to go here, but I sometimes find: Vp a good alternative as it is shorter. Note that the unnamed register will be filled with the previously selected text.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the blackhole register.

Comment: Paste insert mode `<ctrl>-ra` paste register 'a'

Comment: I find it useful to yank into the "p" register.  That way, the paste is "pp

Comment: you don't even need that. See @lwburk answer below

Comment: you're a saint for this

Comment: For those who, like me, use a dead keys keyboard, the key sequence is `"<space>aY`.

Comment: For me, dd is just remove line, not more, so `nnoremap dd "_dd` is enough

Comment: With Neovim (lua config) `nnoremap('d', '"_d')` to delete definitely in normal mode

Answer (score 212):

Your yanked line should still be  in the register 0. So do

```
"0p
```

to paste the line (and delete whenever you want)

Comment: [`:help "0`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#quote0): “Numbered register 0 contains the text from the most recent yank command,
unless the command specified another register with `"x`.”

Comment: This is probably the simplest but effective solution! I've found that all I need is the most-recent yank in 99% cases. And this trick just scratches the itch!

Comment: If you don't want to type `"0p` all the time, you can find a simple way to make `0` the default register for `p` in my answer to a similar question over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-delete-without-putting-text-in-the-register/32488853#32488853

Comment: this is super helpful! i added `nnoremap <C-p> :let @*=@0<CR>p` to my ~/.vimrc, which lets me use Ctrl-p to overwrite the default register with register `0`, and then paste the yanked text

Answer (score 141):

All yank and delete operations write to the unnamed register by default. However, the most recent yank and most recent delete are always stored (separately) in the numbered registers. **The register `0` holds the most recent yank**. The registers `1-9` hold the 9 most recent deletes (with `1` being the most recent).

In other words, **a delete overwrites the most recent yank in the unnamed register, but it's still there in the `0` register.** The blackhole-register trick (`"_dd`) mentioned in the other answers works because it prevents overwriting the unnamed register, but it's not necessary.

You reference a register using double quotes, so pasting the most recently yanked text can be done like this:

```
"0p
```

This is an excellent reference:

- http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/advanced-vim-registers/

Comment: I have always wondered why it was so unpredictable which register text I had yanked or deleted would end up in, and why sometimes it would overwrite and other times not. Thanks for this info!

Comment: Note that the 1-9 registers only get used when the yank or delete is at least one line long. http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#quote_number

Comment: Note that in insert mode you can also use `Ctrl-R 0` to paste last yank

Answer (score 50):

Another possibility is the following:

1. Yank your lines like you would do normally
2. Go to where you want to paste them, enter visual line mode (`V`)
3. Select the lines you want to replace
4. Press `p` to paste your lines.

This also has the added benefit that the buffer is "swapped" with the replaced contents, which I find very conventient

Comment: Great tip - this is definitely something I need sometimes. I find `X` and `P` (holding shift key) tend to do a better job with the newlines, though.

Comment: Your 'added benefit' is actually a hinderance, as it prevents you from repeating your paste operation again. As mentioned in the top example **[here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Replace_a_word_with_yanked_text)**. Alternatively, **[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625722/vim-toggling-buffer-overwrite-behavior-when-deleting/)** suggests a remapping which is probably the most elegant: `vnoremap p "_dp` and `vnoremap P "_dP` I think this is the best solution in combination with your `v`

Comment: The benefit you suggested is exactly what the OP doesn't want, and exactly why he asked this question in first place.

Comment: @fiatjaf: not exactly. The OP wants to paste the copied line over an existing line. Deleting the existing line first will overwrite the current yank buffer. Selecting the existing line and then pasting will swap buffers. This solves the OP's problem (altough you cannot repeat the process if you want to paste the same line multiple times).

Comment: This is EXCELLENT!

Comment: @knittl, I like this solution. Is there a way to do the exact same thing without swapping the buffers?

Comment: @edamondo not that I know of

Answer (score 27):

I use the following mapping to make deleting to the black hole register a bit easier:

```
nnoremap R "_d
```

This way, `dd` becomes `Rd` and `d$` becomes `R$`. Note that `R` is normally bound to enter replace mode, but I found that I never used that, so it was the easisest to remember key for a "really remove" feature.

Comment: I would prefer `nnoremap d "_d` so `dd` remains `dd` and likewise `d$` etc.

Comment: if you did that, wouldn't dd become "_d"_d (not what you want)?

Answer (score 9):

```
" map paste, yank and delete to named register so the content
" will not be overwritten
nnoremap d "xd
vnoremap d "xd
nnoremap y "xy
vnoremap y "xy
nnoremap p "xp
vnoremap p "xp
```

Comment: Wait, how does it help? `dd` still replaces what's been yanked with `yy`, since they write to the same register.

Comment: @EricDuminil I guess he meant "replace x by a different register number for every operation" otherwise is like you said and wouldn't make any sense

Comment: @Santi possibly. It should be explicitely written, then. And x isn't the best placeholder when it's a valid letter.

Answer (score 7):

I wrote [this plugin (yankstack.vim)](https://github.com/maxbrunsfeld/vim-yankstack) to solve this problem. It gives you something like [Emacs's kill ring](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Kill-Ring.html) for vim. You can yank or delete multiple things, do a paste, and then cycle back and forth through your history of yanked/killed text. I find its easier than having to remember what register I yanked something into.

In my .vimrc, I have these mappings:

```
nmap <M-p> <Plug>yankstack_substitute_older_paste
nmap <M-P> <Plug>yankstack_substitute_newer_paste
```

which let me hit ALT-p or ALT-SHIFT-p to cycle back and forth through my paste history.

Answer (score 4):

For your specific question, *as asked*, couldn't you just swap the order of the last 2 steps?

- yank line    (*same*)
- move to new location    (*same*)
- paste yanked line    (*was step 4*)
- delete line you don't want    (*was step 3*)

Granted, I usually use a named register for this type of thing, but sometimes the solution is simpler than what first comes to mind.

Comment: Along the same lines, you could instead replace the last two steps with “select the line or lines to delete with `V`” and then “paste over them with `p`”.

Comment: ^ which, as people have had to comment on many other answers of this flavour, comes with the caveat that yank register gets changed to contain the lines you've just replaced. not fatal for every situation, but worth noting

Answer (score 2):

You could use registers: `"<register><command>`

E.g.:

This yanks a line into register `a`, deletes a different line, and then pastes register `a`

```
"ayy` (move) `dd"aP
```

Comment: Known as "registers" for vim.  "Buffers" means something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try out the following script: [ReplaceWithRegister at vim.org/scripts/](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2703)

Answer (score 1):

I find all these key combos cumbersome.  Instead, I wrote a function to toggle on and off vim's "side effect" behavior of overwriting buffers from delete operations.  That way you can just toggle it off, delete freely, then toggle back on when you're done.

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12649560/778118

To use it just put it in your .vimrc

Answer (score 1):

If you are an evil user, you may consider remapping X to do the equivalent of "_d. However, perfecting the implementation was a little tricky for me. Nonetheless, I found that

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "X" 'evil-destroy)
(define-key evil-visual-state-map "X" 'evil-destroy)

(evil-define-operator evil-destroy (beg end type register yank-handler)
  "delete without yanking text"
  (evil-delete beg end type 95 yank-handler)
)
```

integrates very nicely. For example, typing XX will function analogously to dd, as will X$ to d$, X0 to d0, etc...

If you are curious as to how it works, "95" represents the "_ register, so it simply reroutes your call to delete as if "_ had been the register pressed.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that you know you want to grab something and move, and you are using the 'lazy' first register (which gets replaced by whatever you just deleted).

You need to learn to "cut" in vim.

Before deleting, specify any register different than the `"` one. Tip: check out your registers with `:reg`

now, you select a new register by pressing `"` before any command (in command mode, obviously)

1. select what you want to "cut" (or at step 2 specify a range)
2. Change register to anything (`1` here) and delete: `"1d` or `"1x` or even `"1c`
3. go to new place, delete some more
4. now you are ready to paste what you cut and stored in register 1: `"1p` or `"1P`

done. this also has the advantage of solving the usecase: delete 5 different things from one place, and each piece goes to a different destination... just put one in `"1` another in `"2` and so on... go to each destination and paste.