# Vim: issue regarding copy and paste across different buffer

Tags: vim

I met a problem when copy some lines in one buffer to any buffer.
Here is the details.

For example, I use command '3yy' to copy 3 lines in buffer file1 and want use command 'p' to paste these lines in buffer file2. However, if I do a 'd' command between this two commands to delete some lines in either buffer,  the 'p' command will not work anymore. It cannot paste the content I copied using '3yy' before.
I am on Vim Window 7.

Comment: 'd' not only deletes the lines but is similar to 'cut' operation. take a look at [yank-register](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/meet-the-yank-register/)

Comment: Thanks everyone, I think I got this!

Comment: This is very similar to this post: [Any way to delete in vim without overwriting your last yank?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638542/any-way-to-delete-in-vim-without-overwriting-your-last-yank)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like DOOM said in the comment, 'd' will yank to the default register overwriting what you yanked previously. If you want to preserve what you yanked, place it in a register. Eg:

> "13yy

will place 3 lines into register 1. You can paste them like this:

> "1p

Comment: Numbered registers get overwritten, the named registers (a to z) are probably a better choice.

Comment: Yeah, that's a very bad advice.

Answer (score 1):

The unnamed register contains what you yank *and* what you cut. You can…

- use the `0` register which always contains the last yank: `"0p`
- delete "for real" with the "black hole register": `"_d`.

See `:help registers`.

Comment: A further question. If I want to paste the content in the 5 register for 5 times. How could I do that?

Comment: `5"5p` — that's `count` + `register` + `command`. Note that using number registers like in sashang's answer is a *very* bad idea.