# How to copy only yanked text to system clipboard in vim

Tags: vim, copy-paste

I can copy to system clipboard using `clipboard=unnamedplus`. However this also copies text to system clipboard when using commands like `dd` or `ciw`.

For example, if I copy some text, and then use `ciw`, the text that I am replacing gets copied in the system clipboard and I have to copy the original text again to be able to paste it.

What I want is to copy to system clipboard only when I yank(`y`) a selection, or use commands such as `yy`, `yiw` or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to put this in my `.vimrc`:

```
" Use system clipboard by default
set clipboard=unnamedplus

" Remap 'c', 'C', 'd', 'D', 'x' and 'X' to save text in a custom register
nnoremap c "cc
vnoremap c "cc
nnoremap C "cC
vnoremap C "cC

nnoremap d "dd
vnoremap d "dd  
nnoremap D "dD
vnoremap D "dD

nnoremap x "xx
vnoremap x "xx
nnoremap X "xX
vnoremap X "xX
```

I have found the solution here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21009749/6181757
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1290230/6181757

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to copy to the system clipboard in certain situations, you can use the `"*` register instead of setting `clipboard` globally, eg: `"*yy`.

Alternatively if you want to ensure that a command does NOT go to the system clipboard, you can use a different register or the black hole register `"_`.

For more on registers:

- http://www.brianstorti.com/vim-registers/
- https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/advanced-vim-registers/
- http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard
- `:h registers`

Comment: This doesn't really help. I know I can manually use the registers. What I am looking for is to somehow override the `y` command to copy to the clipboard without having to write `"*` every time.