# How to prevent hitting "dd" from deleting the current yank?

Tags: vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In vim is there a way to delete without putting text in the register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-delete-without-putting-text-in-the-register)

Most of the time, I use `yy` to yank and line and then paste with `p` somewhere. However, if I use `dd` to delete any line, or `dw` to delete any word, I will lose anything that I had yanked. Is there a workaround to this problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same question has been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-delete-without-putting-text-in-the-register/54434#54434) a few times, I think.

You can map the correct command to eg `<leader>d` with:

```
nnoremap <leader>d "_d
```