# How to delete (not cut) in Vim?

Tags: vim, copy-paste

How can I delete a line without putting it into my default buffer?

Example:

```
line that will be copied.

line that I want to be substitued with the previous one.
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
yy
dd
p
```

But Vim replaces the recent copied string with the deleted (cutted) one. I know that I can use buffers like, `"1yy`, `dd` then `"1p`, but I always forget to put the copied string in a buffer then I need to paste my contents first (line that will be copied) and then delete what I want (line that I want to be substituted with the previous one.)

How can I really delete a text in Vi(m) without copying it?

Another related question is how I can forward delete a word in insert mode? I want something similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In vim is there a way to delete without putting text in the register?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-delete-without-putting-text-in-the-register)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Vim is there a way to delete without putting text in the register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-delete-without-putting-text-in-the-register)

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Use the "black hole register", `"_` to really delete something: `"_d`.
Use `"_dP` to paste something and keep it available for further pasting.

For the second question, you could use `<C-o>dw`. `<C-o>` is used to execute a normal command without leaving the *insert* mode.

You can setup your own mappings to save typing, of course. I have these:

```
nnoremap <leader>d "_d
xnoremap <leader>d "_d
xnoremap <leader>p "_dP
```

Comment: thx, you answer my both questions. But I didn't understand how these noremap commands will help me. Am I losing the cut function, right ?

Comment: No, `d` still "cuts" and `p` still "pastes", while `<leader>d` deletes for real and `<leader>p` throws away the selected text and pastes the content of the default register. `<leader>p` allows me to paste the same text multiple times without having to use named registers.

Comment: Don't you mean `nnoremap <leader>d "_dd` and `xnoremap <leader>d "_dd`? As it is now, it waits for the next sequence.

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani this is intended. The point of those `<leader>d` mappings is not to be alternatives to `dd` but to be alternatives to `d`, which waits for a motion.

Comment: Holy cow I can't believe I never new about `<C-o>`. Rad!

Comment: You can just add `noremap <Leader> "_`. With this you keep unchanged your clipboard by pressing your leader key before deleting, yanking or changing

Answer (score 291):

The **black hole register** `"_` will do the trick, but there is a better solution:

When you enter the line back with the `p` command you are pasting the contents of the (volatile) **default register** `""`, which has been overwritten by `dd`. But you still can paste from the (non volatile) **yank register** `"0`, which won't be overwritten by the delete command `dd`.

So these are the commands you want to use as per your example:

```
yy
dd
"0p
```

Comment: Great, this should be the accepted answer. It's much easier to manually specify a register whenever I want to paste than to keep specifying a register every time I delete anything.

Comment: `"0p` does not exactly roll off the fingertips but I think I can get accustomed to this!

Comment: @Jonz I would visually remember it like this. https://imgur.com/sQ2k0NI

Answer (score 72):

That's one of the things I disliked about vim... I ended up mapping `dd` to the black hole register in my .vimrc and life has been good since:

```
nnoremap d "_d
vnoremap d "_d
```

Comment: then how DO you cut?

Comment: `v/V` with `x` is also cut. And cutting with `x` is also coherent with `Ctrl + x` in any OS.

Answer (score 45):

the following mappings will produce:

- d        => "delete"
- leader d => "cut"

```
nnoremap x "_x
nnoremap d "_d
nnoremap D "_D
vnoremap d "_d

nnoremap <leader>d ""d
nnoremap <leader>D ""D
vnoremap <leader>d ""d
```

Also, it is a nice practice to have the "leader" key set to comma,
e.g:

```
let mapleader = ","
let g:mapleader = ","
```

these 2 snippets will make ",d" be your new cut command.

If you would like to use these mappings togther with a shared system clipboard configuration, see further details at https://github.com/pazams/d-is-for-delete

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer more than once -- I was using kprobst's answer but then to cut a line, I had to use `yydd` which was a bit unsustainable on my fingers `;-)`.

Comment: intellij idea acting so weird after this. dd does nothing. ,d does nothing

Comment: I like the solution a lot. One thing that didn't work for me - is cutting lines with `,dd`.
After adding
`nnoremap <leader>dd ""dd`
it started to work

Comment: I'm also having some problems in Intellij with ideavim plugin. The second part, it's not working :(

Comment: Setting the leader key to "," overwrites its "find previous" functionality which is a core feature of movement. I don't recommend it. Mapping leader to space (" ") gives a much better UX.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `"_d` to prevent things from overwriting your yanked text. You can store yanked or deleted text in whatever register you want with `"`, and `_` is the 'black hole' register, where you send stuff that you don't care about.

For more information you can type `:help "_` or `:help deleting`

Answer (score 1):

I use `noremap ' "_` in my .vimrc

This keep the behavior of `dd`, so I can use it to cut as before.

But when I really want to delete something, just use the prefix `'`. For example: `'dd`,`'dw`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with

```
nnoremap p "0p
nnoremap P "0P
vnoremap p "0p
vnoremap P "0P
vnoremap x "0x
nnoremap x "0x
```

Always paste from the 0 register instead of the unnamed one. Use `x` in visual mode to delete into the 0 register.

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution. That consists in copying
`line to copy` over `line to delete`, like this.

Put the cursor at the begin of line of `line to copy` and then enter `ddVp`

- `dd` kill the line to be copied
- `V` select the whole line to be replaced with
- `p` paste the killed line over the visual selection

Now the killed line is in `"1` register, and the copied line
is in `"2` register. Nothing is lost.

I use vim 9, I don't know for which older vim version that works.  If that doesn't work, you can put these lines in your `.vimrc`:

`" Make p in Visual mode replace the selected text with the "" register. vnoremap p <Esc>:let current_reg = @"<CR>gvdi<C-R>=current_reg<CR><Esc>`

Answer (score -1):

```
yy
Vx
p
```

When in visual mode, `x` will delete the selection, so if you want to delete a whole line, first press `V` to select the line in visual mode and then press `x` to delete the selection.

Comment: This copies the deleted line into the clipboard which is exactly what OP wants to avoid.

Comment: Thanks!
Somehow this works perfectly on Emacs's Evil plugin