# Vim pasting -- scroll through previously yanked text

Tags: vim

I am trying to improve the usability of the paste functionality in Vim because too many different deletion operations (in fact I do reckon it's all of them) will also yank to the paste buffer.

What this means is that I am no longer able to delete some piece of text I want to paste somewhere, clean something up, and **then** do my paste. I don't know why this is the order that I prefer to do things, but I'm not about to change it.

I have to basically do the move "atomically" before returning to do clean-up, else I get a frustrating paste of a comma or bracket or space. Oh, I know the reason why I do it in the other order. It's just plain more efficient. I wouldn't have to move to the destination, then **return** to clean up, then **go back again**.

How to improve this? My suggestion is a plugin that can be used to augment the paste operation after the fact. hit `p`, see that it pasted a useless ephemeral deleted char, and at this point (immediately after a paste operation) our plugin will allow a key to cycle through the previously delete-yanked registers, updating our paste in-place.

This way I can delete things all I want, and I'll actually be able to pull up any recent deleted item quickly, so long as it was a contiguous segment. Which is of course easy to set up with a visual selection followed by a delete. This trades specificity for ease-of-use, as I no longer need to remember to specify some specific named register to use for a particular paste.

In particular, there should be a stack that both yanks and deletes accumulate into, that is later quickly traversed during pasting using a single bind.

Is there a plugin out there that already does this?

Comment: I read this 3 times now and I don't get the question. Are you looking for on how to use registers to store different text to be pasted?

Comment: Have you used a plugin like YouCompleteMe? I'm talking about a plugin to retroactively update a "wrong paste" into the earlier one in the yank buffer **in place**. I.e. I hit `p`, `"0` is inserted. I wanna hit `plugin key` to replace the just-pasted `"0` with `"1`, etc.

Comment: Nope, that one was new to me. Tend to keep my vim as clean as possible...

Comment: Sure. YCM is definitely one of the more difficult plugins to get going as it has a native compiled component and requires python... but it's all worth it to me

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You are a bit confused about the numbered registers ([`:h quote_number`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#quote_number)).

There is only one **yank register** and that is **`"0`**.

Separate from that there are nine numbered **delete registers `"1` to `"9`**. These are filled as a queue with the most recent delete at the top.

For the delete registers `"1` to `"9` Vim has the functionality you are asking for built in: You can paste `"1p`, and if it isn't what you're looking for you can repeat `u.` `u.` `u.` to toggle through the registers `"2`, `"3`, `"4`, etc., until you've found the right one. This behaviour is documented at [`:h redo-register`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/undo.html#redo-register).

Scrolling through previously yanked text is most often done with plugins, the most popular ones I know of being

- [***YankRing.vim***](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1234), "Maintains a history of previous yanks, changes and deletes", and
- [***yankstack***](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3834), "lightweight implementation of emacs' kill ring for vim".

Comment: Hey thanks for clarifying this behavior. It's pretty hard to get right without someone explaining it like this (even with, took me *several attempts*). It looks like it requires you to specify `"1p` before the dot will function by continuing up the registers, and like you mention the `u` must be used. Being default functionality, though, this is not too terrible, though it is not practical for my use because having to type `"1p` after `p` fails (which means I gotta hit `u` too) feels way too cumbersome, if powerful. the yankstack plugin is exactly what the doctor ordered. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Why not use a named register? For example, use `"ay` to yank to register `a`, then `"ap` to paste from it again later, and it won't get clobbered by normal deletes etc. in the meantime.

Comment: Right. *I addressed this in the question.* Consider this is at minimum six additional keystrokes, `shift`+`'`+`a` twice. All different keys. In a specific order. This will never be fast. The yanks are already entered into the number-named registers. Just need a way to cycle through them.

Answer (score 5):

```
[l]orem ipsum dolor sit amet

    yiw yanks "lorem" in @" and @0

lorem [i]psum dolor sit amet

    daw deletes "ipsum " into @", @0 still contains "lorem"

lorem dolor [s]it amet

    ciwfoo deletes "sit" into @" and inserts "foo", @0 still contains "lorem"
```

Because register `0` still contains what you yanked (`lorem`), even after a lot of `c`, `d`, `s`, doing `"0p` will *always* paste `lorem` until you explicitly yank something else.

My example only involves what Vim calls "small delete" so the numbered registers are not used; when you do larger operations Vim also uses registers `1-9` but it doesn't change the behavior of register `0` which *always* keeps the latest explicit yank.

`:h registers` is a good and easy to understand read: Vim has a lot of features and plugins are not the answer to everything.

Also, see [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11993928/546861) suggesting the black hole register.