How to map "d" to not save deleted information?
How I can configure "d" mapping in normal/visual/visual-line modes to send deleted information to "_" register by default?
I tried
"noremap d "_d


and
nmap d MyDelete()
function! MyDelete()
    let nr = v:count1
    let cmd = "normal! \"_" . nr . "d"
endfunction

It works but I loose key sequences like d3d...

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11993851/796259
