# How to delete a visual selection without putting text in the register?

Tags: vim

I am essentially trying to achieve the task asked about in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-delete-without-putting-text-in-the-register). The answers do not work when using visual selection.

How would you delete a visual selection in Vim without putting text in the register?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `"_d` does not work (but replaces the selection with the characters), then you're in *select mode*, not visual mode. You need to prepend `<C-g>` to switch modes first: `<C-g>"_d`.

Comment: Thanks @Ingo. That was the key. I was trying to go into visual mode after declaring the register.

Answer (score 1):

Simply select the text then press `"_d`.