# Avoid vim to overwrite system register

Tags: vim

Right now if I copy something on my system, I can paste it in vim by doing:

```
"*p
```

However, if before pasting it, I delete something in vim, when typing `"*p`, I get what I just deleted.

How can I avoid that?

Comment: Do you have something like `set clipboard=unnamed` in your vimrc? If you do remove it.

Comment: I agree with @FDinoff, although it might be set somewhere other than your vimrc file.  Try `:verbose set cb?` to find the current setting and where it was set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the black hole register

```
"_d
```

[In Vim is there a way to delete without putting text in the register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-delete-without-putting-text-in-the-register)

Comment: Or any register other than `*` for that matter.