# Replace word with what's ready to put in vi/vim?

Tags: vim, vi

For example, I have:

```
rm -f $(NAME).elf $(name).d
```

where the second 'name' is a typo, and should also be 'NAME'.

So on 'N', I did <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>, and then moved to 'n'.

I realised that if I now hit <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> to change it, I'll be in insert mode - but I thought ah well, it's only *one* extra key (<kbd>ESC</kbd>) and then I can just <kbd>p</kbd> the corrected version in.

But in that case, <kbd>p</kbd> did exactly what <kbd>u</kbd> would have done, it put 'name' back. I guess because the 'old text' is loaded into the register on change too, which I didn't realise.

---

Is there a "replace with register" command that can be applied to a word/letter/etc.?

Comment: why not simply do "4~" at position n of "name". it will work too

Comment: @Kabir `name` is just an example, it could be `eman` or other typos.

Comment: @Kabir - Kent is exactly right, but that's useful to me too!

Comment: @OllieFord if switching case, you could consider to `guw` `gUw` or `g~w`. this saves you from counting letters (the 4 could be 40).

Comment: @Kent I assume that's for 'switch to lower', '..upper', and 'toggle'?

Comment: @OllieFord vim has a great help doc. read `:h gu`  and `:h gU`...

Comment: The plugin 'easyclip' addresses this issue and others: https://github.com/svermeulen/vim-easyclip

Answer (score 9, accepted):

after you `yw` on `NAME` and moved to `name` you can do:

```
viwp
```

or golf abit: `vep`

Comment: Perfect - thanks. But can you explain this? I want to *learn* vim's command, not memorise combinations :)

Comment: @OllieFord `viw` visual selects the word `name`, now if you press `p`, the selected objects would be replaced by the unamed reg's value.

Comment: Ah got it! I've only used shift+V for visual line until now.

Answer (score 2):

I need this so often, I wrote a plugin to simplify and allow maximum speed: [ReplaceWithRegister](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2703).

This plugin offers a two-in-one `gr` command that replaces text covered by a {motion} / text object, entire line(s) or the current selection with the contents of a register; the old text is deleted into the black-hole register, i.e. it's gone. It transparently handles many corner cases and allows for a quick repeat via the standard `.` command. Should you not like it, its page has links to alternatives.

#### Your example

With `NAME` yanked into the default register, and the cursor on the `n`, just use `gre`. `gr` invokes the command, and `e` is the motion that covers the entire `name` to be replaced.

Comment: Thank you - I'll check it out when I've to grips with the basics. I've  been advised (youtube) to learn the basics, plugin-free, at first. I've accepted Kent's answer only because it answers my specific question with default config.

Comment: That's a good approach. The difference between the two is that with Kent's answer, you'll override the default register's `NAME` with `name`, so you can do that replacement only once (without re-yanking), whereas mine can be reapplied as often as you want (even with the `.` command).

Comment: Ah I hadn't realised (only the one typo this time) - I assumed I could use `.` still. I think I'll certainly be back here to install your plugin soon - like you say I'm sure I do this (until now with copy-select-paste) all the time!

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way:

```
ciw<Ctrl-r>0
```

or

```
ce<Ctrl-r>0
```

This would allow for repeating with `.` without the use of any plugin, as you mentioned on the comments that you are currently avoiding them.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply change the case of `name` with `gUiw`.

Comment: Please see comments on OP, this was suggested, but my intention was for a method of replacing a word with whatever's in the register - i.e. would work for a typo like NMaE too.