# How to disable vim pasting to/from system clipboard?

Tags: vim, editor, clipboard

Basically, I need advice on how to do the **opposite** of what is described here:

[How to make vim paste from (and copy to) system's clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489428/how-to-make-vim-paste-from-and-copy-to-systems-clipboard)

I **do not want** vim to overwrite system clipboard when I delete something within the editor. The usual workflow for me is to select a piece of code (let us call it piece #1) with a mouse, then go to another piece of code (let us call it piece #2), select piece #2 in visual mode in vim, delete it using "c", and paste piece #1 using mouse middle button. With the new behavior, instead of pasting piece #1 I paste back piece #2.

In vim 7.2 I can do that, but in vim 7.4 I can not. I want to use 7.4 due to proper C++11 syntax highlighting but this changed default behavior is killing me.

I think, it has something to do with the *"+xterm_clipboard"* and/or *"+clipboard"* features of vim (*vim --version*), and I need to change them somehow to *"-xterm_clipboard"* and/or *"-clipboard"*. I tried to recompile vim 7.4 with the option *"--with-x=no"* but somehow it did not help.

Please, help me to disable copying/pasting in vim to system clipboard by default.

Thank you!

Comment: You have two options. First, better avoid that clipboard register. Second, map it or set it to other register. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, to answer the question in your title, you can just do

```
:set clipboard=
```

Which will make vim use it's internal register instead of the system one.

But really, this behavior has nothing to do with the system clipboard. It's more just a general misunderstanding of vim registers.

Vim by default "cuts" rather than "deletes". This means that every delete command (`c` and `d`) yanks to the unnamed register at the same time. To get around this, just use the black hole register, e.g. use `"_c` or `"_d` instead of just doing `c` or `d`.

```
9. Black hole register "_               *quote_*
When writing to this register, nothing happens.  This can be used to delete
text without affecting the normal registers.  When reading from this register,
nothing is returned.  {not in Vi}
```

To make this the default behavior for your specific case, you can do

```
xnoremap c "_d
```

The 'x' in 'xnoremap' means this mapping applies to visual mode (with v) and select mode (with the mouse)

[Related SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-delete-without-putting-text-in-the-register).

Comment: (this is a comment to the previous version of your reply) Thank you very much! **":set clipboard="** does the trick for me :) If you reverse your answer back to advice me to ":set clipboard=", I will accept it ;)

Comment: @S.V Glad I could help! Also, just so you know, there is also a [dedicated vim site](http://vi.stackexchange.com/) if you have more questions down the road.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, I did not know about http://vi.stackexchange.com/ - somehow my google searches led me here, instead of the dedicated vim site.

Answer (score 2):

check

```
:h clipboard-unnamed
```

This extension may be also of use to you http://vimawesome.com/plugin/easyclip